# VB -- How to test for value not in dropdown

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a large VB/SQL application that I have created a problem in. I have a table of procedures that have an active flag on them. This flag can be toggled through a user screen. Other screens access this same table to populate dropdowns. The values are stored in the table as the ID field (PK). The problem I have is that I am selecting the dropdown values based on the Active flag. If I select a record that has a procedure stored in it that has been made inactive, I get the old Object Not Set to an Instance.... error.

What I want to be able to do is check for the value in the record when populating the dropdown and allow the record to be displayed by bypassing the SQL error and just showing the dropdown value as blank while not altering the record itself. I hope I'm making sense. Code is below -- pretty vanilla stuff, but I'm back in app programming after being a SysAdmin for 20 years and I'm still rusty.

**Library code**

```
Public Function GetDropDownList(ByVal strDropDownList As String, _
                                ByRef objSession As System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState) As String

    Dim strSQL As String = ""

    Select Case strDropDownList

        Case "SurgicalProcedure_ID"
            strSQL = "SELECT [ID]=0,[Description]='' " _
                   & "UNION " _
                   & "SELECT [ID],[Description] " _
                   & "FROM dbo.viw_List_SurgicalProcedures " _
                   & "WHERE ISNULL(Active,0) = 1 " _
                   & "ORDER BY [Description] ASC"
```

**VB code-behind**

```
        With objSqlCommand
            .Connection = mobjSqlConnection
            .CommandText = "SELECT * " _
                         & "FROM dbo.viw_tblCaseProcedure " _
                         & "WHERE [ID] = " & Session("CASE_ID").ToString
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        End With

        objSqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(objSqlCommand)

        objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objSqlDataSet)

        objSqlDataRow = objSqlDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)

        objDropDownList = Me.SurgicalProcedure_ID
        strStringValue = objSqlDataRow("SurgicalProcedure_ID").ToString()
        If strStringValue = "" Then strStringValue = "0"
        objDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(strStringValue).Selected = True
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your approach, but at a guess, the problem seems to be at this line:

```
objDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(strStringValue).Selected = True
```

The start would be to do this instead to avoid the Object Not Set error:

```
Dim ddlItem as ListItem = objDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(strStringValue)
If ddlItem Is Nothing Then
    ' Insert 'blank item' code here
Else
    ddlItem.Selected = True
EndIf
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: rskar, that seems to be the right direction. But the "Is Nothing" won't work. On the Select from that view, a valid value is returned. I think I to need to add columns/logic to the table and SPs that operate against it. If the procedure is marked inactive, the value returned from the select is not in the dropdown because of the WHERE ISNULL condition in the Library code. And I can't update the table value because of historical issues (Procedure can still be valid for an old case, but not for new ones). And old cases need to be accessible.

Comment: @rskar, I didn't put the @ sign in front of your name. Thanks for your input and see my comment above.

Comment: @Joel - do you mean to say that you have a need to show an "inactive" selection for the sake of a record that - once upon a time - had that now inactive procedure as one of its values?

Comment: @rskar - Yes, unfortunately. It's a medical provider application. Not a HIPAA requirement, but it is a Medicare requirement -- 5 years on records retention.

Comment: @Joel - Looks like you'll need to somehow bring back the relevant "inactive" row. Are you able to do any SQL query during the VB code-behind? Like maybe do that when strStringValue = "0" (since, I reckon, the ID of interest is known - via Session("CASE_ID")). Is there a view or table that you could query to get the "inactive" [Description] you want?

Comment: @rskar - You just got the gray matter working. I can create a parallel table with views that contains inactive procedures. If I do the equivalent of "NOT IN" when querying the active table, then I can query the inactive table. The original ID would have to be a data column, not the identity seed. If the customer reactivates the procedure, just delete it from the inactive table. I'll play with this concept. Thanks.